# Next Auth + Prisma - Google auth/ Github auth error

Tags: next.js, prisma

When I try to configure Github auth or Google auth using the next auth and prisma I get this error with both of them http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error?error=OAuthAccountNotLinked

Or sometimes this one http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error?error=Callback when using google.

This is how my provider is setup

```
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET as string,
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
```

Comment: This repository should help you in figuring out the issue: https://github.com/hexrcs/prisma-next-auth
This could work as a reference